# what will it gets if two resolutionStrategy with different version number from different libs/sdks?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Come across this situation and not clear what would be the result that one lib's gradle has `resolutionStrategy` to force to use one version of `'play-services'`,  and the other lib also wants to force to use a different version.

One lib could be added as dependency in the other lib. What would be the final result of what version of the `'play-services'` to be picked in the build?

in one lib it has:

```
allprojects {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms' && details.requested.name.startsWith('play-services')) {
                details.useVersion("11.0.2")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

the other one has:

```
allprojects {
configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy {

        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms' && details.requested.name.startsWith('play-services')) {
                details.useVersion("15.0.1")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}